# How to plot Hermite Curve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, equation, curve, hermite

I need to plot exactly this graph in MATLAB:
[image: hermite plot]

I am struggling with writing hermite vector functions as the vectors showed like they correspond to just last 2 rows of the matrixs in figure.

In MATLAB I wrote equations as below, but I didn't understand why it shows only the last two.

```
equation1 = (1/3)*t^3+(1/2)*t^2;
equation2 = (1/3)*t^3-(1/2)*t^2;
equation3 = t^4+5*t^3+t^2+t;
equation4 = t^4+5*t^3+t^2+t;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can I see your plotting code?

Comment: It doesnt show anything, I assume these functions are wrong and i didnt understand about declaring inital value of t

Comment: Read [ask] and very importantly [mcve]